# Spring + two data sources - primary and fallback

Tags: java, spring

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. I have two databases, both of them have identical schema and contain table X
2. Normally I always use the first DB to read data
3. Under some condition, I set a flag
4. When the flag is set, I first read the entity from the first DB, but when it's not there, I also check the second DB

Could you please tell me, how could I achieve it with Spring?

Comment: How do you intend to access the database: plain JDBC, JPA or else?

Comment: I would prefer to use JPA.

Comment: I don't see how to do it without building a subclass of entity manager and entity manager factory. This will need some serious prototyping though. Entity manager would know both data sources and get access to the flag. The `find` methods of entity manager would implement your use case. However if you also need `getSingleResult` and `getResultList` on `Query`, this approach will involve too much work, and I don't see how to do it any other way.